# Page always takes at least 30 seconds to load

Tags: 7

I have a site set up on Godaddy and a constant frustration is that it always takes at least 30 seconds to load. Total time for queries was under 200ms. I decided to write the following script:

```
function getmillisecs() {
   list($usec, $sec) = explode (' ', microtime());
   return (double) $sec + $usec;
}

$start = getmillisecs();

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$end = getmillisecs();

$result = $end - $start;

echo round($result * 1000, 3);
```

All it does is output how much time passes between the start and end of the script. The time I got was 30521.649ms. Taking out everything related to Drupal dropped the time to 0.089ms. What is causing the huge delay? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be several things:

- Views executing sql queries that have performance problems.
- Cache problems (Do you have enabled the Drupal's cache?).
- (If you have a VPS) maybe the server that you are sharing is under heavy load.
- (If your site is integrated with web services) maybe the web service is having performance problems or connection problems.

Try to check the logs of the site to see is there are errors or anything that could be related to this problem.

Another alternative is to use a profiler like Xhprof (there is a [module for drupal](https://drupal.org/project/XHProf)) or XDebug.

Could you share with us the url of the website?

Comment: turned out the culprit was a module my client added. load times got cut down by 90% when I took it out.